# Javascript Alert not showing in "Dreamweaver Live View"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I have a problem with code below. The alerts are not working in "Dreamweaver live view" CC 18. It works fine in jsfiddle or codepen. Everything else seems to be working in Dreamweaver except for the alerts. I believe that the JS scripts are referenced correctly. I want this to be an offline project. Please help.

- The code compares table one's cells colours to the other tables and is supposed to display an alert when there is a match.
- You can change the colour of table one's cells by selecting one of the top left buttons (white, yellow or red).
- The code below is exactly what I have in Dreamweaver.

I really appreciate any help. Thanks.

```js
// js/index.js
jQuery(function() {
  var brush = "white_block";

  jQuery('input.block').on('click', function() {
    brush = jQuery(this).data('brush');
  });

  function cellCheck() {
    $one = $("#one").html().replace(/\s/g, '');
    $two = $("#two").html().replace(/\s/g, '');
    $three = $("#three").html().replace(/\s/g, '');
    $four = $("#four").html().replace(/\s/g, '');
    $five = $("#five").html().replace(/\s/g, '');

    if ($one === $two) {
      alert("match with two");
    }

    if ($one === $three) {
      alert("match with three");
    }

    if ($one === $four) {
      alert("match with four");
    }

    if ($one === $five) {
      alert("match with five");
    }
  }

  jQuery('td').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('white_block yellow_block red_block').addClass(brush);

    cellCheck();
  });
});
```

```css
/* css/style.css
*/

.block {
  border: thin solid #000000;
  width: 59px;
  height: 57px;
}

.white_block {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.red_block {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.yellow_block {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}

table {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Blocks</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <br> Buttons:
  <br>
  <input type="button" class="block white_block" data-brush="white_block">
  <input type="button" class="block yellow_block" data-brush="yellow_block">
  <input type="button" class="block red_block" data-brush="red_block">
  <br>
  <br> Table One:
  <table id="one">
    <tr>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
      <td class="block white_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br> Table Two:
  <table id="two">
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br> Table Three:
  <table id="three">
    <tr>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br> Table Four:
  <table id="four">
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <br> Table Five:
  <table id="five">
    <tr>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block red_block"></td>
      <td class="block yellow_block"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery.min_2.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Stop using Dreamweaver and just load it in the browser.

Comment: Maybe dreamweaver is stopping it on purpose? i mean... alerts are pretty terrible for... pretty much everything.

Comment: Geuis - I tried using it directly in the browser and it works. So perhaps it is the dreamweaver live view. - Thanks.